# Titanium open url with a done button in browser window

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

In Titanium I know it is possible to open a URL in a browser like so:

```
Ti.Platform.openURL("http://example.com/foo");
```

However this opens it up in a browser like this:

[image: normal]

Compare that to other iOS apps like Slack and it looks like this:

[image: Slack Browser]

As you can see at the top it has a done button and it is not possible to change the url. There is also an option to open it up on Safari.

Open it up on Facebook messenger iOS app and it looks like this:

[image: fb browser]

How can I change the way Titanium opens URL's on iOS so that it uses a browser like the one used in Slack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is the native component for that, which is wrapper by Appcelerator in the module `ti.safaridialog`. You can see specs about it in the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.SafariDialog)

Add it to your app

```
<module platform="iphone">ti.safaridialog</module>
```

And then use it

```
var dialog = require('ti.safaridialog');
if (dialog.isSupported()) {
    dialog.open({
        url: 'http://appcelerator.com',
        title: 'Titanium rocks!',
        tintColor: 'red'
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks like SafariDialog is now deprecated in favor of: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/titanium-web-dialog

Comment: Thanks for that @DiegoFreniche. That is indeed the cross platform replacement